# Box Rest APIv2: Download Deleted File returns 500: Internal Server Error

Tags: box-api

I'm unit testing my code with the APIv2.

The scenario is as follows:

1. Upload new file, say it returns id "12345"
2. Delete the new file
3. Try download the deleted new file id "12345"

Result: 500 Internal Server Error

I know it shouldn't really happen, but I'm expecting error something like 404 not found. I'm fairly confident its not my code as downloading valid file works.

Am I reasonable to expect for code other than 500?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the intended error code. As the resource no longer exists, we should be returning a `404 Not Found`. We'll be fixing this shortly.

Comment: Moving file to deleted folder also fails with 500 Internal Server Error.